# Kibana 5.5 visualization data aggregation percentage

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-5

I'm using Kibana 5.5 and would like to create a visualization that shows percentage of successful transactions made to my server.

In order to do that I have a field in the document named "httpCode" and I would like to get the percentage of "httpCode: 200" out of the total transactions made.

I managed to put this in visulalization that does separate lines, but I would like to get percentage over time and not count.

Thanks,
Moshe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new bar or area chart and choose count as aggregation, set your field for `Date Histogram`. Next in buckets tab add `Split Series` and choose `Filters` as `Sub Aggregation`. Your first filter should look like that:

```
Filter 1
httpCode:200
```

Use `http.keyword` instead if is available.

```
Filter 2
NOT httpCode:200
```

Go to Metrics & Axes tab, expand `LeftAxis-1` and change `mode` to `percentage`:

[image: Metrics & Axes example]

On my exmaple it should look like that:

[image: Exampel chart]